# Connect to outlook.office365.com from linux server using proxy in python

Tags: python, linux, proxy, imap, imaplib

I am trying to connect to outlook.office365.com from a Linux server as I want to fetch unread mails.

Below is the code-

```
 def start_connection(self):
    msrvr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com', 993)
    msrvr.login(self.username, self.password)
    return msrvr
```

Error :
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvCro.png)

As I can't get direct access to outlook.office365.com on port 993, I need to go through a proxy server, of which IP and port are available to me.

How can I modify my code to use the proxy server. 
I am working on python version 2 on RHEL 7.6.

Comment: Please do not put text into screenshots.  Please copy and paste the error.